# Variable reference not working in echo command in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I created two files with exact same data 'a','b','c','d','e' in separate rows 
1. testing_office.csv file from ms office 2019.
2. testing_txt_editor.csv using sublime text
 Following is shell script which is used.

```
object_type=$1

for object in `cat ${object_type}`
do
echo "test before object reference" ${object}
echo ${object} "random text after the object reference"
done
```

i am running the code via zsh shell Following are the commands used and outputs

```
argarvit >>% ./testing.zsh testing_office.csv 
test before object reference a
a random text after the object reference
test before object reference 
 random text after the object reference
test before object reference b
 random text after the object reference
test before object reference c
 random text after the object reference
test before object reference d
 random text after the object reference
test before object reference e
e random text after the object reference

argarvit >>% ./testing.zsh testing_txt_editor.csv 
test before object reference a
a random text after the object reference
test before object reference b
b random text after the object reference
test before object reference c
c random text after the object reference
test before object reference d
d random text after the object reference
test before object reference e
e random text after the object reference
```

Why are the two files acting different if there is some text after the reference? The issue might be with encoding but how do i figure out the exact reason? I tried opening testing_office.csv on text editor it looks the same. I tried on MBP as well as AL2 getting same results on both the terminals.

Comment: try to use `md5sum *.csv` to calculate the MD5 of files, and use `file -i *.csv` to get character-set encoding.

Comment: @GarvitArora : Obviously your files are different. Use `diff` to see the differences.

Comment: @GarvitArora: A side note: If this is really the **complete** script you posted, it does not use zsh in the way you execute it. You would have to run it as i.e. `zsh testing.zsh testing_office.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [Useless Use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), alas I cannot recreate your problem.  Likely there is a core difference between the files stated.  You can `od -c` each file to check.

You may want to try a `while read` loop instead of backtick expansion:

```
while read object ; do
        echo "test before object reference" ${object}
        echo ${object} "random text after the object reference"
done <$1
```